# Programatically push a view controller once certain conditions have been met

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

The code for pushing to the next view controller when a user enters a correct username and password (and presses the button) brings up the error:

**"Cannot find type 'NextViewController' in scope"**

How do I resolve this? Or is there a better line of code to implement for this?

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: UITextField!
    
    let usernames = ["username1", "username2", "username3"]
    let passwords = ["password1", "password2", "password3"]
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! NextViewController
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(button2)
        usernameTF.delegate = self
        passwordTF.delegate = self
    }
    
    private let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame =  CGRect(x: 20, y: 480, width: 382, height: 50)
        button.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Login), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let button2: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame =  CGRect(x: 20, y: 730, width: 382, height: 59.5)
        button.setTitle("Sign Up!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .init(UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 200/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0))
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 10)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        return button
    }()
    
    @objc func Login() {
        passwordTF.resignFirstResponder()
        
        if (usernameTF.text!.count) < 6 || (passwordTF.text!.count) < 6 {
            
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "Please Check you have the right login details", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
        else if usernameTF.text == usernames[0] && passwordTF.text == passwords[0] {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct!", message: "We're in.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else if usernameTF.text == usernames[1] && passwordTF.text == passwords[1] {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct!", message: "We're in.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        else if usernameTF.text == usernames[2] && passwordTF.text == passwords[2] {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct!", message: "We're in.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect", message: "Incorrect Username or Password! Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == usernameTF {
            passwordTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == passwordTF {
            Login()
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error specifically?

Comment: You said 'The below code brings up an error of "scope", although I have no idea how to resolve this.' That is too vague to be helpful. What is the complete error message? Is it a compile-time error or a runtime error? What line is the error on?

Comment: @DuncanC Apologies, I have rephrased the question. It is a compile - time error, and I do not know how to resolve it. The error is on line 18.

Comment: It's a completely straightforward error. The phrase `as! NextViewController` implies that you believe there is a class called NextViewController. The compiler says you're wrong. Show us the code where you think you are declaring `class NextViewController` please.

Comment: SO posts don't include line numbers. Tell us the contents of the line. And add the info to your original question, not to comments. (A future reader should be able to understand your question by just reading the question, and not have to wade through a series of "20 questions" comments where you provide dribs and drabs of information.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says, your error "Cannot find type 'NextViewController' in scope" tells you that the compiler doesn't recognize the type `NextViewController`

The only place you reference the type `NextViewController` is this line:

```
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! NextViewController
```

You try to cast the view controller that's returned by the call to `storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to a type of `NextViewController`, but the compiler doesn't know what that type is.

I would expect to see a file in your project named "NextViewController.swift" that looks something like this:

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    //The contents of your NextViewController class would go here
}
```

If you don't have a definition for a `NextViewController` class, that is the cause of your problem. If you do define a `NextViewController` class, the compiler isn't able to find it for some reason. Post more info if that's the case and we can try to help you figure out the cause.